# sql server insert extract blob data

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, blob, varbinary

i have a code that inserts a image or pdf in a sql server table i think that inserts fine but when i have to extract de data to show in html page, not shows nothing. i see a lot of examples and thq queries seems to be good. i don't know where is the mistake, the code is the following:

php code that receives the values from the form :

```
$destino = addslashes( file_get_contents( $value['tmp_name'] ) );

$tmpName = $value['tmp_name'];

$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

$destino = ($data);

fclose($fp);

$tamano = $value['size'];

$tipo   = $value['type'];

$nombre = $value['name];

$sql="INSERT INTO documents 
    ( nombre, archivo,extension ) 
    VALUES 
    (:nombre, cast(:archivo as varbinary(max)), :extension )";

$valores = array(

    ':nombre'       =>$item->nombre,
    ':archivo'      =>utf8_encode( $item->archivo ),
    ':extension'    =>$item->extension);
```

i checked in the database and inserts well.

when i execute a select query to get the stored values and shows in the webpage i have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT nombre,CAST(archivo as VARCHAR(MAX)) as archivo,extension from documents WHERE id= :id";

$valores=array(':id' => $id );
```

finally in have this code to print the image or pdf in the view.

```
$doc = $servi->findDocById( $_GET['id'] );

header("Content-type: {$doc->extension}");

echo ( $doc->archivo );
```

this shows in the view nothing. anybody knows where is the mistake?

thanks

Comment: Is the syntaxe error on your example only in your example? Can you also check what is the `Content-type` returned by the page? Did you check the logs to be sure that error reporting is not yelling something there instead of the page (prod config for example)?

Comment: Not sure why you have the first line `$destino = addslashes( file_get_contents( $value['tmp_name'] ) );` as you then redo the read again later

Comment: i have no syntax error, the value of **content type is image/jpeg** i have php errors enable and php shows me 0 errors

Comment: Its normal to `base64encode()` a image before storing it.

Comment: I am also kind of interested to know where `$item->archivo` came from as an object called `$items` has not been mentioned in the previous code

Comment: So I think we are down to the GIGO level now.

Comment: where i would do the base64enconde() ?

Comment: `$nombre = $value['name];` **is a syntax error**, just look at the script color coding

Comment: _where i would do the base64enconde() _ Instead of the `utf8_encode( $item->archivo ),` but using a varibale that contains the image data would be good as well

Comment: I think we could be suffering from the good old `copy/paste` from different sources with mind in neutral problem here

Comment: Also you `utf8_encode( something )` when you store the image but you do not reverse the encoding when you read it back to put it on a web page. Like I said earlier, I am pretty sure `utf8_encoding` an image is wrong, but it is definitely wrong not to undo the encoding when you read the blob back

Comment: if i not do **utf8_encode(something)** sql server tells me **An error occurred translating string for input param 2 to UCS-2**